# Two Navigation Drawers on Same Activity with Different top alignments

Tags: android

I got some problem on Navigation Drawer Activity. I have 2 Navigation Drawers in same activity and one of them (left/start) should open over the action bar and other one (right) should display below the Action bar. So I set the top margin (56dp). But it works fine only for below version of Lollipop. 
please can you tell me a solution for that if somebody knows.

Thank you.

This is .xml file that I have tried.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="end">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    layout="@layout/app_bar_new" />

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_food_hub_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_food_hub_main_drawer" />

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_filter_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/drawer_top_margin"
            android:background="@color/colorCartItem"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:stateListAnimator="@anim/fade">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorCartItem">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/colorCartItem"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="16dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/sort"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/spinner_sort"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/bottom_border_solid"
                        android:padding="15dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/quickFilters"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/checkBoxHomeCook"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/bottom_border_solid"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:text="@string/homecook"
                        android:textSize="15dp" />
    ..............................

                </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have the correct value for `drawer_top_margin` defined in all versions of your `values` folders?

Comment: I set top margin for both dimens & dimens(v21) --> 56dp. Is it ok?

Comment: I would think so. Still, you might try hard-coding `android:layout_marginTop="56dp"` to test. Also, what's it doing, exactly, when it doesn't work? Does it look like you just don't have a margin there?

Comment: yes I have tried. But still in Lollipop versions it shows like there is no top margin which means right drawer open over the action bar. not below.  In below versions of Lollipop show with top margin which means show below the action bar.

Comment: Well, the first suggestion that comes to mind would be to put the `NavigationView` inside another `ViewGroup`; e.g., a `FrameLayout` or a `LinearLayout`. It sounds like Lollipop is ignoring the margin because it's a drawer, but it should at least handle it correctly inside another `ViewGroup`. If you try this, make sure to move the `layout_gravity` attribute to the outer `ViewGroup`.

Comment: No still had the same problem

Comment: <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/nav_filter_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_filter_view1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorCartItem"
         ............

Comment: No, sorry, I meant leave the margin on the `NavigationView`.

Comment: Thank you very much Mike. It works fine now.